# How to get an multiple images/icons inside a street view panorama and set their position and height?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

How do you get images/icons inside a street view panorama and place them at specific points and heights? Like the following demos?

In the Google maps API you can use markers but you cannot set the height at which they sit at..

[image]

**Demo links:** 
https://insideabbeyroad.withgoogle.com/en/all-access/studio-2/2035#x=0.205&y=-0.205&z=-0.957

https://www.tourengage.com/view-tour/1467f5f3-2b14-4961-a5f0-15e23dc169af/